# Guice unbounded generic binding

Tags: java, generics, guice

I want to provide generic instances without explicitly stating generic parameters inside module implementation.

Let's say I have a very optimized Map implementation and want everyone to use that.

```
class MyVeryOptimizedHashMap<K, V> implements Map<K, V> {}
```

I know, following usage is not the best design pattern, but for the sake of the example, this is a valid requirement:

```
class SomeInjectee {
  @Inject
  private Map<String, Integer> myMap;
}
```

To bind this instance to provider of my choice following module declaration works:

```
class GenericMapModule extends AbstractModule {
  protected void configure() {
    bind(new TypeLiteral<Map<String, Integer>>() {}).toProvider(new TypeLiteral<Provider<MyVeryOptimizedHashMap<String, Integer>>>() {});
  }
}
```

Problem is that I have to explicitly state generic type parameter, which I cannot possibly do for all possible types:

```
class SomeOtherInjectee{
  @Inject
  private Map<SomeUnknownKey, Long> myMap;
}
```

This solves my problem but not very elegantly:

```
class GenericModule extends AbstractModule {
  protected void configure() {
    bind(new TypeLiteral<Map<?, ?>>() {}).toProvider(new Provider<Map<?,?>>() {
      public Map<?, ?> get() {
        return new MyVeryOptimizedHashMap();
      }
    });
  }
}

class SomeOtherInjectee {
  private Map<SomeUnknownKey, Long> myMap;

  @Inject
  void setMap(Map<?, ?> mapInstance) {
    myMap = (Map<SomeUnknownKey, Long>) mapInstance;
  }
}
```

What I am looking for is something like that:

```
class GenericModule extends AbstractModule {
  protected void configure() {
    bind(TypeLiteral.anyGenericVariant(Map.class)).toProvider(new TypeLiteral<Provider<MyVeryOptimizedHashMap>>(){});        
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If applicable in your case I'd try a static utility method.

```
class SomeOtherInjectee {
    private Map<SomeUnknownKey, Long> myMap = newOptimizedMap();
```

If this is not applicable then as you see Guice is very precise in terms of generics i.e. each generic variant represents a unique binding. So the anyGenericVariant would actually had to list all of the possible variants and make the binds ahead of time. Crazy.

In such cases what you can do is to register a custom injection using the TypeListener. It would look like

```
class SomeOtherInjectee {
    @InjectOptimizedMap private Map<SomeUnknownKey, Long> myMap;
```

or whatever the custom injection annotation you make.

See [here for the full example and explanation](http://code.google.com/p/google-guice/wiki/CustomInjections) on how to do custom injections.

Comment: As I mentioned, this is an example, my actual use case is different than this one. So I need to solve this problem, inside my module definition (probably using some private constructors of Key or TypeLiteral classes) and leave injectees as is. Guice is actually pretty lazy, if only Key<->TypeLiteral matching could be hacked.

Comment: What is wrong with going with TypeListener way? Do you need c'tor injection?